# How to find the point on a parabola where x and y are equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, graphing-functions, conic-sections

On a parabola how could i find the point at which the y and x points are equal and meet on a point of the graph, algebraically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x$ for $y$ in the parabola equation and solve for $x$.

Comment: I see what you mean perhaps my question was poorly phrased. If the only information i have is the x values and corresponding y values from points 0-19 which create a parabola. Using that information how could i find the point where my x and y are equal              x= 0 y= 8,5
x= 1 y= 8,14
x =2 y = 7,778

x =7 y =6,26

x =10 y =5,7

x =13 y = 5,5
  I know that when x = 6,4 y = 6,4 but how could i find that based on the above knowledge only?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

In the given equation of parabola. Substitute y = x, and solve the quadratic equation for x.

Answer (score -1):

Replace x with y or y with x and solve for the unknown variable. Then, the value you get will be valid for x=y.